# How to prevent text from moving when centered and range slider value changes?

Tags: html, css, slider, range, center

Let's say I have some HTML like this:

```
    <div style = "text-align: center">
      Radius: <span id = "radius">1</span><br>
      <input type="range" id="chosenRadius" oninput="updateRadius(this.value)" onchange="updateRadius(this.value)"  min="1" max="1000000" value="1" /><br>
    </div>
```

Whenever the slider is moved, the `span` updates with the current value of the slider. The `div` within which everything is located centers everything. How can I keep the "Radius:" text from moving at the length of the number within the `span` changes? I do not care if it's not exactly centered after the value of the radius increases, but as long as it is close. I would like for this setup to start out centered and then for the "radius:" text to remain fixed. [Here is a simple JS bin.](https://jsbin.com/nifipoluva/edit?html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#radius {
  position: absolute;
}
```

this shows it: https://jsbin.com/forarasuze/1/edit?html,css,output

an `absolute` position will will keep it still for you